# Initializing SparkContext inside another SparkContext object

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, grid-search

I'm using PySpark to distribute a machine learning operation which consists of the following steps:

1. Read data
2. Divide data based on a column (~100 columns, dividing on one column that has 50 unique values, hence need to distributing the process on this column)
          I am parallelizing this process using sc.parallelize method
3. On each data, initialize a classifier through a pipeline and use GridSearchCV from spark_sklearn to parallelize this operation. Since this requires it's own sparkcontext, I am creating another spark context object for this inside the small function.

A sample code is below

### sample code

```
sc = SparkContext('local', appName="abc")

def sample():
    ## some code

    ## read data and extract text features using pipeline
    ## use grid search CV from spark_sklearn package -- this requires its own sparkcontext
    sc1 = SparkContext('local', appName="xyz")
    grid_search = sp_GridSearchCV(sc1, clf, parameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, verbose=1, scoring='f1_macro')
    grid_search.fit(X, y)
    sc1.stop()
    return grid_search

results = sc.parallelize(labels).map(sample).collect()
sc.stop()
```

I would like to know if this would be the correct way of doing this and if not what would be the best way. I think the process can surely be improved. For example, initializing the sparkobject everytime adds an extra overhead which can be minimized

Any directions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not how Spark works.

When you create a SparkContext you are setting up your cluster, getting all information from YARN about how is your cluster. How much resources and stuffs.

SparkContext is responsible to handle this resources, hold the metadata for your RDDs, DataFrames, DataSets. And it will distributed between your workers. You can see below:

[image]

You can check with more details about it in [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-architecture.html) link.

But why that is not going to work, and why if its works you would be losing resources.

**Why it will not work**

Calling spark context in the worker side you will create a new "driver" and according to spark architecture you can just have drivers in the master node.

**Why it will not give performance improvement**

Spark always try to use all the resources of your cluster if you are using dynamic allocation to run that. And due to the [Catalysis Optimizer](https://spark-summit.org/eu-2016/events/a-deep-dive-into-the-catalyst-optimizer/) this will create a plan of execution that in the most of times is better than what we used to build manually. And if you were able to create SparkContext in the workers side you would loose that executor just for the driver so, losing resources.

Comment: this makes sense and I had the same in mind. Would have any idea how to distribute gridsearch for multiple models in Pyspark. Thanks

Comment: You can definitely have the driver run on a worker node.  It's called --deploy-mode cluster

Comment: @nEO You can submit multiple Spark jobs to YARN at the same time and have them run simultaneously.  You would just have to adjust the resources each job takes and also maybe tune YARN to better handle your shared pool of resources.

Comment: but running a driver on each of the worker nodes, is that a good practice and would it give performance boost as what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I like your thinking but **after you have Spark Context, think of it as a lazy single machine which does one job at a time**. The only difference between the usual single machine & spark context single machine is awesomeness(ram/processing/coordination/resilience).

It's pretty much considered as bad idea to send a map with a function containing ParamGrid. But above logic will help you :)